# getValue setter not storing value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am using firebase and passing the values to a listview

to pass the value to the listview i use the following

```
requestList request = requestSnapshot.getValue(requestList.class);
```

i also need to store the key for the record, but it is not included within the getValue call.

I decided to write my own setter for the key and add it to the requestList class

i am setting the key manually like this

```
request.setrequestKey(requestSnapshot.getKey());
```

when i print the values of request to the log directly after adding them i get the correct values

```
 Log.i("Chat", request.getRequestTitle()+": "+request.getRequestDescription()+"    "+request.getrequestKey());
```

returns this

```
RequestTitle: RequestDescription    -KK4yufLTSScKHzvZtM4
```

i then wanted to use the request.getrequestkey within an onclicklistener like this

```
 messagesView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
        requestList o = (requestList) messagesView.getItemAtPosition(position);

        String requestKey = o.getrequestKey();

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),requestKey,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

however the requestKey is null but the requestTitle and requestDescription is present and correct

i cant understand why the class isnt retaining the value

can anyone help please

here is my requestList class

```
public class requestList {

    String RequestTitle;
    String RequestDescription;
    String requestKey;

    //DataSnapshot requestSnapshot;


    public requestList() {
    }

    public requestList(String RequestTitle, String RequestDescription) {
        this.RequestTitle = RequestTitle;
        this.RequestDescription = RequestDescription;
        //this.key = key;

        //this.requestSnapshot = requestSnapshot;
    }

    public String getRequestTitle() {
        return RequestTitle;
    }

    public String getrequestKey() {
        return requestKey;
    }

    public String getRequestDescription() {
        return RequestDescription;
    }


    public void setrequestKey(String requestKey) {
        this.requestKey = requestKey;
    }
}
```

i am now including the full class as per comment requests

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_request, container, false);

        final ListView messagesView = (ListView) myView.findViewById(listView);


        test mApp = (test) getActivity().getApplication();

        //test mApp = ((getView())getApplicationContext());
        String UID = mApp.getUID();

        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/" + UID + "/Requests" );

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot requestSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //requestList request = requestSnapshot.getValue(requestList.class);
                    requestList request = requestSnapshot.getValue(requestList.class);
                    request.setRequestKey(requestSnapshot.getKey());
                    Log.i("Chat", request.getRequestTitle()+": "+request.getRequestDescription()+"    "+request.getRequestKey());

                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.e("Chat", "The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });



        ListAdapter mAdapter = new  FirebaseListAdapter<requestList>(getActivity(), requestList.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, ref) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View view, requestList requestListItem, int position) {
                ((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(requestListItem.getRequestTitle());
                ((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(requestListItem.getRequestDescription());

            }


        };


        messagesView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                requestList o = (requestList) messagesView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                String requestKey = o.getRequestKey();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),requestKey,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        messagesView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        return myView;



    }
}
```

I am now including the database values

```
{
  "AccountID" : "ABC123",
  "Created" : "today",
  "Name" : "value",
  "Requests" : {
    "-KK4yufLTSScKHzvZtM4" : {
      "RequestDescription" : "Request Description 3",
      "RequestItems" : {
        "-KK4yv8qnh7YHe7WuJ8B" : {
          "Description" : "Item Descriptiopn",
          "Title" : "Item Title"
        },
        "-KK4yv8rPsnJr824rAON" : {
          "Description" : "Item Descriptiopn",
          "Title" : "Item Title"
        },
        "-KK4yv8s3ivK7Mfx166H" : {
          "Description" : "Item Descriptiopn",
          "Title" : "Item Title"
        },
        "-KK4yv8tKoM2sV1gyOkz" : {
          "Description" : "Item Descriptiopn",
          "Title" : "Item Title"
        }
      },
      "RequestTitle" : "value"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code for `requestList` class.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla i have updated the above

Comment: Got it. So are you saying that if you do `o.getrequestKey()`, and does `o.getRequestTitle()` return anything? - If unsure, you can change `o.getrequestKey()` to `o.getRequestTitle()`   and make a `Toast` of the value.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla that is correct, i have just changed getrequestKey to getRequestTitle and it returns the correct value

Comment: Interesting, please include the code where you declare `messagesView` and set its adapter- I want to see where the call `messagesView.getItemAtPosition(position);` is getting its items.

Comment: Try changing `getrequestKey()` to `getRequestKey()`.  I think the capitalization is important.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla i have updated the question again to include the complete class

Comment: @qbix i have tried changing the case on the getRequestKey() but it has not changed anything. When i inspect the object the key is null

Comment: Does your Firebase data model include the said `requestKey`? Because this might be why the adapter does not populate this - and this also explain why it works when you set the key manually (`request.setRequestKey(requestSnapshot.getKey());`) - but this is not possible in the adapter. Can you please include the screenshot that shows how your data looks.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla i will add a screen shot to the question in 1 moment. I can confirm that the getKey() is returning the correct key. The dataSnapshot does not contain this key as it gets the children and iterates through. I need the underlying key (parent)

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla i have added the database to the question. I chose to copy the JSON output rather than screenshot as it slightly easier for me

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla did you have any more ideas, im still stuck on this :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using FirebaseUI, you don't need to track the key yourself. You can easily get it with `adapter.getRef(...).getKey()`:

```
messagesView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
    requestList o = (requestList) messagesView.getItemAtPosition(position);

    String requestKey = adapter.getRef(position).getKey();

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),requestKey,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: when you say requestKey = adapter. Which adapter is it as there is no such variable defined. I have tried both the firebase reference (ref) and the listAdapter (mAdapter) and both fail

Comment: Are you using [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)? If so, you have implemented a subclass of `FirebaseListAdapter` or `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: I am using FirebaseUI, and ive use a FirebaseListAdapter. Not sure sure if i understand "implemented a subclass". Ive called it in the ListAdapter mAdapter = new  FirebaseListAdapter line.

Comment: if i change the ref to final then it allows me to call the getRef() method, however it doesnt accept any parameters. getRef() in Query cannot be applied to (int)